# Device Orientation Incorrect When Notification Banner Appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uidevice

I have an app that is monitoring the "orientation" property of `UIDevice`. All is well except for whenever a push notification or SMS (anything that triggers a banner notification to appear above the app) shows up, the UIDevice class reports `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait`.

This feels like a bug, but I'm not sure if anyone else has seen this or knows it is expected.

Comment: Can you clarify, your question?

Comment: Even though I have the device face down, if a notification arrives, such as an SMS or e-mail, [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation starts reporting UIDeviceOrientationPortrait, which is wrong.

Comment: Can you please confirm return value of `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` method inside your **appdelegate.m**. For all oriantation support it must return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`.

Answer (score 0):

By adding below method to your **AppDelegate.m** class your app must be able to support all types of device orientation.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; 
}
```

Also you can check all device orientation as shown in image 
[image: Device orientation in iOS app]

Good Luck